# I need Ansible to start my EC2, discover the public IP and change this in two files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

Iam new to aws and wrote some playbooks for creat, start and stop EC2 instances. This works very well.

Now I have to figure out the public IP and change the IP in 2 files on the EC2 instance.

I've tryed several code snippets to add the "figure out public IP" - thing but nothing works for me.

My playbook:

---

```
  - name: Starting an EC2 Instance
    hosts: local
    connection: local
    vars_files:
    - aws_keys.yml
    tasks:
    - name: starting ec2
      ec2:
        key_name: ansible
        aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
        instance_ids: ['i-0f3xxxxxxxxxxxx']
        region: eu-central-1
        state: running
        wait: true
```

Ive tryed this:

```
- name: ip
command: curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
register: myip

- debug:
var: myip
```

But it shows me only the IP from my ansible controlemachine....

Is it possible, to add this public IP - thing into my EC2-start Playbook or do I need a seperate playbook for this?

Today I've tryed the following:

```
- ec2_instance_facts:
        region: eu-central-1

      register: ec2_metadata

    - debug: msg="{{ ec2_metadata.instances }}"

    - debug: msg="{{ ec2_metadata.instances[0].public_ip_address }}"
```

I've get this error:

TASK [ec2_instance_facts] **********************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1547803855.77-249661690870165/AnsiballZ_ec2_instance_facts.py\", line 113, in \

Do I need for the ec2_instance_facts section the aws_secret_keys too?

Ahhh with the aws keys it works:

```
- ec2_instance_facts:
        region: eu-central-1
        aws_access_key: Axxxxxxxxx
        aws_secret_key: Gz8+Dxxxxxxxxxx
        instance_ids:
          - i-0f31xxxxxxx
```

Now I need to write the public IP in a var and use this for updating 2 files on the EC2-instance which are starts with the playbook.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34394672/getting-the-ip-address-attributes-of-the-aws-instance-created-using-ansible and https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_instance_facts_module.html

Comment: @jarmod thank you for the links. Do you have any idea for my updated problem?

Answer (score 0):

For fethching the publicIP, storing it in a variable and then updating two files with it try using something like boto3 sdk for python to fetch the PublicIP details and use ansible for updating the two files with that IP.